# Works for .Formula but not for .FormulaArray

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which works absolutely fine when i use Activecell.Formula... but gives me a 1004 Unable to set the FormulaArray property of Range Class when i use Activecell.FormulaArray

```
     Sub CreateFiberLossReport()
    '
    ' CreateFiberFiles Macro
    '  - by Shikhar Parashar
TotalJoints = Range("F3").Value
For freqCtr = 1 To 3
freqSheet = Choose(freqCtr, "1550", "1625", "1310")
'fiberNum = "001"
    For n = 9 To 176
        For TJNum = 2 To TotalJoints + 1
            ColToSelect = Choose(TJNum, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z")
            Sheets(freqSheet).Select
            rangeValue = ColToSelect & n

            Range(rangeValue).Select
            initPath = "C:\Users\Deepak\Desktop\Fazilka ferozpur AT\FRZ-JLB\["

            formulaValue = "=VLOOKUP(MIN(IF(ABS('" & initPath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & ".xls]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & "'!$C$17:$C$28-" & ColToSelect & "5*1000)=MIN(ABS('" & initPath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & ".xls]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & "'!$C$17:$C$28-" & ColToSelect & "5*1000)),IF(ABS('" & initPath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & ".xls]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & "'!$C$17:$C$28-" & ColToSelect & "5*1000)< 150,'" & initPath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & ".xls]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & "'!$C$17:$C$28,))),'" & initPath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & ".xls]" & (n / 3 - 2) & " " & freqSheet & "'!$C$17:$E$28,3,FALSE)"
            ActiveCell.Formula = formulaValue
        Next
    Next
Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect your formula is too long. `FormulaArray` is limited to 255 characters so you have to use placeholders and replace parts. You can search for examples as this has been asked before.

Comment: From the docs at [Range.FormulaArray Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837104.aspx).

>If you use this property to enter an array formula, the formula must use the R1C1 reference style, not the A1 reference style.

>The FormulaArray property also has a character limit of 255.

Answer (score 0):

Your left square bracket is in the wrong position in `initPath`.  It should be at the start.

This is bad practice.  You should have the left square bracket in the `formulaValue =` statement rather than in the variable itself.

eg.

```
formulaValue = "=VLOOKUP(MIN(IF(ABS('[" & initPath & (n / 3 - 2) & " " .......
```

Comment: I did try that... but didnt work... hence had to resort to the place where i kept it

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The whole point of the square brackets is to "escape" the workbook name that includes special characters such as spaces and back slashes. The name must be in the form [c:\folder\file.xlsx]Sheetname!Range. What you have is not that and it will cause a 1004 error.